# Recovering drivers from previous installation?

Tags: windows, networking, drivers

Yesterday I bought a new computer and I've been setting it up since this morning. The hard drive came with windows 7 home premium (x64) installed, but I decided to instead install windows 7 ultimate (x64) - this is what I'm currently using. Unfortunately, there were some drivers that were installed that I need in this installation. I only notice because the computer doesn't have the ethernet drivers, so I'm only able to connect to the internet via wireless. There are other drivers missing as well, but I'm not yet seeing the effects.

I still have the Windows.old folder with the previous installation, which has the drivers. Is there any way to copy the necessary ones over? I tried the options for updating driver software through device manager with the path set to System32\drivers of the old installation, but it didn't find anything.

Comment: Within the Device Manager try to update from MS instead of local diver copy.

Comment: It will be faster and better to just download the most up-to-date drivers for the hardware, even if it means downloading it on another computer and copying them over on a flash drive.

Comment: @climenole, I tried that as well.

Comment: @DarthAndroid, How do I know where to find the drivers? I couldn't find a definitive model number for the ethernet controller.

Comment: OK Walkerneo: so check my answer. The easiest solution imho. :)

Comment: @Walkerneo Worst-case, if you view hardware properties in the device manager, go to the `Details` tab and select `Matching device ID`. The value will contain `VEN_XXXX&DEV_YYYY` where the `X`'s and `Y`'s are 4-digit hex-codes. Google "`ven XXXX dev YYYY`" and look at results to see what brand & model they correspond to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update and install the required drivers from *Ma-Config* Web site:

[Find appropriate drivers at Ma Config](http://www.ma-config.com/en)

This web site ask you to install a Browser plugin (certified by Kaspersky) and a Service to detect the required drivers. Start the detection, select the WHQL drivers, download and install the divers.

N.B. Install one driver at the time and create a restore point *before*.

Comment: Wow, beautiful site and very helpful. Only qualm is that it's in French!

Comment: There's an english version of this site. Isn't?

Comment: @climenole I append /en to the end of the url and it does switch to english http://www.ma-config.com/en

Answer (score 1):

In your situation where windows can't find a driver, it's best to look at the PCI ID for that device.  Open device manager and locate the unknown driver, right click on it to select properties and go to the details tab.  In the drop down menu, navigate to Hardware Ids.  For example, an intel Gigabit connection will look like this

PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1503

Then go to the [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/index.php) and enter your device ID information to figure out what the actual hardware might be by entering your vendor and device number (8086 and 1503 in this example, respectively).  From there you can search the internet for drivers from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

What is all this talk about downloading programs and browser plugins to locate drivers? Go to the manufacturers website and download them from there. Keep in mind they may not have drivers for the Ultimate version of Windows 7 - something that you should have checked up on before installing.

Comment: Drivers compatible with Windows 7 home premium will work with Windows 7 ultimate.